# GitLab CI: avoid duplication of skip-ci for each job

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci, gitlab-pipelines

Currently, I'm duplicating the information about `skip-ci` in every single job, like so

```
job1:
  except:
    variables:
      - $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /skip-ci/
    ...
job2:
  except:
    variables:
      - $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /skip-ci/
    ...
job3:
  except:
    variables:
      - $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /skip-ci/
    ...
```

Is there any way to write it only once and it'd apply for all the jobs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways to do this in GitLab:

- [Job inheritance using extends](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#extends)
- [YAML Anchors](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#anchors)

#### Job Inheritance

This is the recommended approach, since it's more readable than YAML anchors and you can extend from multiple jobs if you need to. In the following example, the period in front of the job name causes GitLab to hide the job so the template job doesn't get executed on its own.

```yaml
.skip-ci:
  except:
    variables:
      - $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /skip-ci/

job1:
  extends: .skip-ci
    ...
job2:
  extends: .skip-ci
    ...
job3:
  extends: .skip-ci
    ...
```

#### YAML Anchors

I've included this approach for completeness, but generally it's almost always better to use `extends`.

```yaml
.skip-ci: &skip-ci
  except:
    variables:
      - $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /skip-ci/

job1:
  <<: *skip-ci
    ...
job2:
  <<: *skip-ci
    ...
job3:
  <<: *skip-ci
    ...
```

Answer (score 9):

In case you are not relying exactly on `skip-ci`, Gitlab already includes logic for this:
When a commit message contains `[skip ci]` or `[ci skip]`, the pipeline is skipped, according [to the docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/index.html#skip-a-pipeline).

Comment: Interesting, wasn't aware of. Definitely will check it out! PS. Would be good to link the exact hyperlink https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#skip-pipeline, because the GitLab's docs is soo huge.

Comment: Actually, the link is already set to the one you proposed (you can see it when hovering over the link), but for me (and probably also you), the position of the page is a bit off (like half a page to the bottom).
Does also happens when clicking on the link you posted, at least for me.

Comment: For me it doesn't happen, checked `Opera` and `Safari`.

Comment: This indeed works best, but the question was slightly different therefore left the original answer accepted :) Thanks tho, will use the `[skip ci]` thing. It's not written in the docs, but `[skip-ci]` works too!

Comment: Docs link has changed again: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/index.html#skip-a-pipeline

Comment: @JinnKo Thanks, I changed the link in the answer!

Answer (score 0):

The full functionality can be achieved when you allow all posibilities. You typically include `[ci-skip]` or `[skip-ci]` in your commit message, it will skip automatically. Note that `[SkIp cI]` will work too..

From GitLab source code

```
SKIP_PATTERN = /\[(ci[ _-]skip|skip[ _-]ci)\]/i
```

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/pipeline/chain/skip.rb#L10